# Conditional cumulative sum in R with dplyr. All dates before current date

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a way use a cumulative sum within R with the condition of not including the current date.

I have the following data frame (which is a subset and simplified version of the real data frame):

```
df <- structure(list(date_time = structure(c(1609513200, 1609513200, 1609513200,
  1609516800, 1609516800, 1609516800, 1609599600, 1609599600, 1609599600, 
  1609603200, 1609603200, 1609603200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
  "POSIXt")), event = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
  person = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), 
  did_attend = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
  events_attended = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2), 
  events_attended_desired = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), 
  class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -12L), groups = structure(list(person = c("A", "B", "C"),
  .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L), c(2L, 5L, 8L, 11L), 
  c(3L, 6L, 9L, 12L)), ptype = integer(0), 
  class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
 
 df
 ## date_time           event person did_attend events_attended events_attended_desired
 ## 2021-01-01 15:00:00     1 A               1               0                       0
 ## 2021-01-01 15:00:00     1 B               1               0                       0
 ## 2021-01-01 15:00:00     1 C               1               0                       0
 ## 2021-01-01 16:00:00     2 A               1               1                       0
 ## 2021-01-01 16:00:00     2 B               1               1                       0
 ## 2021-01-01 16:00:00     2 C               0               1                       0
 ## 2021-01-02 15:00:00     1 A               0               2                       2
 ## 2021-01-02 15:00:00     1 B               1               2                       2
 ## 2021-01-02 15:00:00     1 C               1               1                       1
 ## 2021-01-02 16:00:00     2 A               1               2                       2
 ## 2021-01-02 16:00:00     2 B               0               3                       2
 ## 2021-01-02 16:00:00     2 C               1               2                       1
```

The column "did_attend" is a dummy variable which signifies if a person attended the event. The "events_attended" column has obviously been produced by

```
events <- events %>% 
  arrange(date_time) %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(events_attended = lag(cumsum(did_attend), default = 0)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Now I am looking for a way to not include the events of the current date, so the cumulative sum should only sum over the dates prior to the current date (The desired output is in events_attended_desired column). There are several events each day and the number of events is different on each day. So a lag version does not work. I tried several ifelse() in the cumsum function but they didn't work either because I don't know how to compare the dates in an ifelse clause within cumsum()

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `dplyr` and `lubridate::floor_date`.

First, I add a "date" column to the data frame, so that I can summarize and join based on the date.

Then I join this table to a summarized version of itself. `count(date, wt = did_attend)` is a shortcut for `group_by(date) %>% summarize(n = sum(did_attend))`, so if I then take the lag of that, we get the desired result.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::floor_date(date_time, "day"))

df2 %>%
  left_join(
    df2 %>% 
      count(date, wt = did_attend) %>%
      mutate(prior_attended = cumsum(lag(n, default = 0))) %>%
      select(-n)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply each number by 1 if it corresponds to a prior date and 0 otherwise.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
   mutate(events_attended = sapply(as.Date(date_time), 
      function(x) sum((as.Date(date_time) < x) * did_attend))) %>%
   arrange(date_time) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: This works just fine. Thank you very much.